# How to wire a mono signal to a stereo jack so both channels are the same

Tags: audio, signal

Can I just divide the wiring and send the same signal parallely to left and right channel?

I have a feeling there's more to it than just that.

Comment: hi welcome to SSE. what have you tried already? this is audio basics, did you search elsewhere?

Comment: Also, it would help to know what the output is like and what the inputs are like. What kinds of connectors and what kinds of devices. In some cases you can just divide the signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to divide the part of the mono cable dedicated to the **Tip** into two equal copper cables and solder one to the **Tip** and the other one to the **Ring** part of your **TRS** jack (stereo) the other cable stays on the **Sleeve**.